# I got following error while build Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I got following error while build Android-ndk Please help me.

**Cygwin.bat**

```
@echo off

set IS_UNIX=
set DEV_ROOT=C:/iliu-Android-NDK-Fibonacci-a546a1a
set JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin
set CLASSPATH=C:/iliu-Android-NDK-Fibonacci-a546a1a/obj
set PATH=D:/new_eclipse/android-sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows/tools;D:/new_eclipse/android-sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows/android-ndk-r7
set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/d/new_eclipse/android-sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows/android-ndk-r7
set NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/cygdrive/C/iliu-Android-NDK-Fibonacci-a546a1a


C:
chdir C:/cygwin/bin

bash --login -i



**Error:**


$ ./ndk-build
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
/cygdrive/d/new_eclipse/android-sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows/android-ndk-r7/build/core/build-local.mk:102: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

I got following error while build Android-ndk
Please help me.

Answer (score 9):

You have to call ndk-build from your project directory, so in pseudocode,

```
cd $MyProject
$NDK/ndk-build
```

Comment: Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'CocosDenshion/android'
 in import path
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?

Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
jni/Android.mk:19: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.

Answer (score -1):

you should call ndk from the of your project 
like that :

```
C:\Users\Xhunter\AndroidStudioProjects\mupdf\platform\android\viewer>C:\Users\Xhunter\Downloads\ndk\ndk\ndk-build
```